# Questions are repeating when used order by rand in php online exam system

Tags: php, mysql

Questions are repeating when used order by rand in php online exam system

```
if(isset($_SESSION['stdname'])){
    $result=executeQuery("select stdanswer,answered from studentquestion where stdid=".$_SESSION['stdid']." and testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn'].";");
    $r1=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $result=executeQuery("select * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn']."order by rand();");
    $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: 1.`mysql_*` is a deprecated( in PHP 5.5 (in 2013)) and removed(in PHP 7 (in 2015)) library in a newer version of PHP. So please upgrade yourself asap. 2. it's quite possible that multiple time `rand()` produce the same number for search what is actually happening.

Comment: use `distinct` operator

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Distinct works on column not on rows so it is absolutely useless here to use. 1) Stop using mysql It is deprecated. 2) rand can gives you duplicate result because it provides you random rows not unique random rows. 3) Use `group by` with one of your column and then do order by rand

Answer (score 0):

Use the key word `DISTINCT` in your query.

```
$result=executeQuery("select DISTINCT * from question where testid=".$_SESSION['testid']." and qnid=".$_SESSION['qn']." order by rand();");
```

Also mysql_* is deprecated. Follow @Magnus's comment

Comment: Distinct evaluates column not rows. so according to distinct these both rows are distinct

this is question 1
this is question 2

And as a result you will get repeating column again.

Comment: i tried converting the code by converting from mysql to mysqli but still nothing worked same result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "ORDER BY RAND" in the query, grab all the possible questions. Once you've got the questions into an array, use the shuffle() function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomise the questions. Then all you need to do is use a for loop to get the required number of questions.